# stop when the character appears second time while file reading + components for graph C++

Tags: c++, file, graph, while-loop

Hello I have a small problem I am trying to load from one file to another.
Here is the problem : the infile contains     graph: **something** graph:     something2 etc.
And I need only to load that **something**(between graph: and graph:), but in the second file cant be written graph: only the **something**.

And later I need to count components of a graph I already have function for counting the components of graph, but I need to load only one graph write the components then clear it and load the second and etc. I have 9graphs in that file. Any idea how ?.
Here is my code :

```
void load2()
{
  ifstream infile;
  infile.open("graph.txt"); //input file
  ofstream outfile;
  outfile.open("out.txt"); //output file

  while (!infile.eof()) {
    char c = infile.get();

    if (c == 'g') {
      break;
    }

    while (!infile.eof()) {
      char c = infile.get();

      if (c == 'g') {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { //delete 6 characters include g (graph)
          infile >> c;
        }
      }

      outfile << c;
    }
  }

  infile.close();
  outfile.close();
}
```

Comment: If the contents of the file are "graph:foo bargraph:goo bellgraph:gorillagraph:nonsense" do you want to emit "foo bar", "goo bell" and "gorilla"?  Or do you only want "foo bar" and "gorilla"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `graph:` and `something` are separated by whitespace

```
void load2()
{
  ifstream infile("graph.txt");
  ofstream outfile("out.txt");

  std::string graph, something;

  while (infile >> graph >> something) {
    if (graph != "graph:") {
      break;
    }
    outfile << something;
  }
}
```

---

The following should handle the format explained in your comment

```
std::string token;
while (infile >> token) {
  if (token != "graph:") {
    outfile << token;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but 
graph: **something** graph: **something2** etc. something contains more then one letter for example: 
graph:
Q  R
J  A
graph:
P  L
L  A
graph:
.
etc.

Comment: Thanks, but 
The graph.txt contains : 
[link](http://postimg.org/image/hn5wyakgt/)
and I need to get only the prompted but with spaces between them because I am loading them and they are vertices of a graph

Comment: Try and adapt the code I posted, you can use `getline` to read each line and output it to the other file if it doesn't match the graph token.

Comment: One more question, please how can I fix this
[link](http://postimg.org/image/s9cunz5il/)

here´s my code

`void load2(){
 ifstream infile;
 infile.open("graf.txt");
 ofstream outfile;
 outfile.open("out.txt");
 std::string line;

 while(!infile.eof()){
  
   while (getline( infile, line)){
    if(line == "graf:"){
     infile >> line;
     }
    if (!line.empty()){   
  outfile << line;
   outfile << '\n';
  }
 
 }
 } 
 // infile.close();
 // outfile.close();
 }`

Comment: You should probably open a new question, but anyway http://pastebin.com/5WvdxSSb .

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it using C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const std::string target{"graph:"};
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: graph filename\n";
        return 0;
    }
    std::string line;
    std::size_t t1;
    std::size_t t2;
    std::string output;
    std::vector<std::string> answers;
    bool emitting = false;
    for (std::ifstream in(argv[1]); std::getline(in, line); ) {
        t1 = 0;
        for (t2=line.find(target); t2 != std::string::npos; 
             t2 = line.find(target,t1)) 
        {
            if (emitting) {
                output += line.substr(t1,t2-t1);
                answers.push_back(output);
                output.clear();
                // emitting = false;
            } else {
                emitting = true;
            }
            t1 = t2+target.size();
        }
        if (emitting) {
            output += line.substr(t1);
            output += '\n';
        }
    }

    for (const auto &s : answers) 
        std::cout << "[" << s << "]";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

If your file contents is:

```
graph: Q R J A graph: P L L A graph: A B C D graph:
```

this program will print:

```
[ Q R J A ][ P L L A ][ A B C D ]
```

If you intended to have it only print between matching pairs of your **graph:** token, uncomment the commented out line and it will then print

```
[ Q R J A ][ A B C D ]
```